# Increment hour if minutes exceed 60 android

Tags: android, time, android-seekbar

I have two SeekBar in my application. One shows hours and the other progresses in interval of 15 minutes (0,15,30,45).

I have a initial value of time set to 10.30. Iam displaying the changed time in a TextView.

Now, if the user only increments the minute seekbar (eg 15 mins) the textView should show 10.45. (ie. 10.30 + 00:15). Similarly, if the user further increments the minute seekbar to 30 or 45 the TextView should show 11:00 and 11:15 respectively.

Currently, Everything works fine until the minutes goes upto 15 minutes. But when I increase the SeekBar to 30 or 45 the TextView shows 10:60 and 10:75 instead.

Here is my code:-

```
int hourLimit=10, minLimit=30;
    seekBarHour.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {


        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {


        }



        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
            if(progressChangedHours == 0 && progressChangedMins==0)
            {
                txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching by:"+" "+String.valueOf(hourLimit)+":"+String.valueOf(minLimit)+":"+today.second);
            }
            if(progressChangedHours==0 && mins >=60)
            {
                hour = 1;
            }
            else
            {
            hour = hourLimit + progressChangedHours;

            }
            timeString = String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(mins)+":"+today.second;
            txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching by:"+" "+timeString);
        }





    }); 

    seekBarMins.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {


        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            progressChangedMins = progress;
            int stepSize = 15;

            progressChangedMins = (progressChangedMins/stepSize)*stepSize;

        }



        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {

            if(progressChangedMins == 0)
            {
                txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching by:"+" "+String.valueOf(hourLimit)+":"+String.valueOf(30)+":"+today.second);
            }
            else
            {


                mins = minLimit +progressChangedMins;
                if(progressChangedHours==0 && mins!=0)
                {
                    hour = hourLimit;
                }
                else if(progressChangedHours>=0 && mins>=60)
                {
                    hour = hour+1;
                    mins = mins-60;
                }


                timeString = String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(mins)+":"+today.second;
                txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching by:"+" "+timeString);
            }
        }



    });
```

> EDIT

: I used the Date to solve a part of my problem like so:-

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Date date;
        try 
        {
            date = sdf.parse(initialTime);
            cal= Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);

            txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching By:"+" "+ cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

seekBarMins.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {


            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                progressChangedMins = progress;
                int stepSize = 15;

                progressChangedMins = (progressChangedMins/stepSize)*stepSize;
                seekBar.setProgress(progressChangedMins);
                if(progressChangedHours ==0 && progressChangedMins!=0)
                {
                    lblLateBy.setText("Late By (Hrs):"+" " + String.valueOf(progressChangedHours) +":"+String.valueOf(progressChangedMins));
                }

                else
                lblLateBy.setText("Late By (Hrs):"+" " + String.valueOf(progressChangedHours) +":"+String.valueOf(progressChangedMins));



            }



            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
            {

                if(progressChangedMins==0)
                {
                    timeString = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+today.second;
                }
                else
                {
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, progressChangedMins);

                timeString = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+today.second;
                }
                txtReachingBy.setText("Reaching by:"+" "+timeString);

            }



        });
```

Now everything works fine if I drag the seek bar thumb at once to a value. The progressed value gets added to the initial time. But if I drag it to a value the initial time changes with the addition, then again if I drag it further the progressed value gets added to the new time and not the initial one.

Giving me the output as:-

```
Drag 1-> 15 mins > Time expected 10.45 (Fine)
Drag 2-> 30 mins > Time expected 11.00 Output I get -> 10.45+00.30 = 11.15
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should not let them progress individually. Just monitor the time. Then set both progress bars according to time. Use the Date class for instance. Ok and if the user does it by hand then do some little calculations with minutes.

Comment: You should really solve this yourself as you exactly know where things go wrong and what has to be done.

Comment: @greenapps I have used Date class which solves a part of my problem. I have posted a fresh question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820406/add-seekbar-progress-to-initial-value-android It would be great if you could help.

Comment: Why are you posting a fresh question? Keep it here.

Comment: `I have a initial value of time set to 10.30`. Ok. If you have done that. Do the seekbars take that position? Is the one on 10 and the other on 30? Or can you set the time to 10:30 and both seekbars are to the left and displaying both 0? In the last case the seekbars are used to add time to 10:30.

Comment: Just answer my questions first as i have to understand what you want.

Comment: @greenapps I have two seek bars. 1 is for hours(0-10) and 2nd for minutes (0,15,30,45). At first both seekbars are at position 0. I have a String initialTime =10:30 which I convert into a time. So whenever seekbar values change with hours or minutes i display another String timeString with the values added to my initialTime

Comment: @greenapps right now if I drag the seek bars at once the time gets updated perfectly. But if drag the seekbar further the value is then added to the updated time and not the initial one

Comment: So they are used to add time. You should have stated that from the beginning. I still think you can solve your problem yourself. And all that code... You dont need so much code. You don't need all those listners to keep track. You only need a little bit of code in onStopTracking where you read the positions of the bars and do a little calculation with total hours and minutes.

Comment: @greenapps I know there should be a simple way. I am just confused right now. Can you help me witha sample

Comment: Throw away most of your code. int starthours =10; int startmin = 30; And in onStopTracking: int hours = starthours + hourbar.position; int minutes = startmin + minbar.position; Well that is for a start. After this you add hours and minutes.

Comment: @greenapps I had tried this. When I do this I start facing a problem after the number of minutes go over 60

Comment: Yes of course. But then you have to add all hours and minutes. int totalmin = hours*60 + minutes; Well if you have that.. if you have a lot of minutes.. can you calculate how many hours that would be and how many minutes left?

Comment: @greenapps I think my second approach got me what I wanted. Iam still stuck with the problem when I drag the thumb, stop (here time gets updated), then again drag further(here the updated time gets updated again instead of the initial time).

Comment: Just implement the six or seven codelines i suggested in onStop and you are done. Throw away the overkill.